# ASP.Net MVC 5 - Solution Architecture - Areas for Segregating Concerns - Further Segregation

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am playing at solution architecture for an Intranet Web Site. I have used a single project approach instead of a multiple project approach given my limited understanding of sharing resources between them.

I want to segregate departments within the company. I see areas as the solution to this problem, but now I need to segregate within those departments. I am unsure how to approach this situation.

Solution > Project > Areas > Department

The architecture above works fine, but when I try to use the context menu to add an area inside an area, I cannot. I am sure this is by design so I'm wondering what is the approach I am meant to take?

Comment: This is way too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: Is this just an intranet with mostly static content? Or is there lots of interactivity and data input required? If it's mainly static then I would just use a CMS system for this, unless you want to re-publish your application every time the company re-arranges its department names or they want to add new pages to the site or correct a typo or change a photograph. Even if there's some interactivity in certain areas, most modern CMS systems let you build that in via plugins or special content

Comment: Depending what do you want to do with the Department, you could use a Controller per Department, adding actions in each Department. Let us know more about the context or the responsibilities that you need for get the best solution.

Comment: @maccettura Thanks for your opinion

Comment: @maccettura It's not entirely opinion based as he is trying to do something that the system won't let him.  It is possible to explain why that is, and a suitable alternative, without entering in to opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC's architecture separates the *physical location* of code files from the *virtual location* of the code that is executed (the URL). You can modify the URLs using *routing* to change the locations that the resources are *virtually located*. This is all that the end user sees.

Areas are only 1 level deep. But the URLs of where Areas are located can be modified according to your requirements.

Alternatively, if the goal is to make the physical location and the virtual location match (which really only matters to the developers that are maintaining the application), there is an open source project called [MvcCodeRouting](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting) that can be used as a hierarchical multi-level replacement for Areas.

Comment: My goal is to be able to segregate departmental concerns to the Nth level. I should have specified that. Physical location in the project is important to me, I want to make developer navigation easier.

Comment: Then I suggest you check out [MvcCodeRouting](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting). Areas in MVC cannot be organized in a hierarchy out-of-the-box, but that project extends MVC to make it possible to make your namespaces/folder locations and URLs match up perfectly.

Comment: I will research this when I get home, work has github blocked :( I appreciate the insight and the time you have taken to try and understand my goal

Comment: Marking as answer, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of MVC Areas is not to reflect the structure of your organization, but to *bundle related pieces of functionality*. E.g. you could define areas named `Employees`, `Benefits`, `CompanyCars`, `Expenses` etc.

Also by definition, only 1 level of Areas can exist. So either you have areas, all Area Controllers are then living 1 'level' below the root of the site (and if you want, you can still also have root level Controllers). Or you don't have areas, all Controllers will then exist next to each other at root level.